# Adding text after a input value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have tried creating a currency website with a little HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

But I have one problem, I want to display the different currencies after the input value.

Ideally I would like to display "GBP", "EURO", "USD" directly after the numbers.

[image]

I have tried converting the numbers to a string, and concatenating it with the text but it won't work.

My JS looks like this.

```js
    let dkInput = document.getElementById('dkk');
    let usdInput = document.getElementById('usd');
    let gbpInput = document.getElementById('gbp');
    let euroInput = document.getElementById('euro');


    dkInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
       let dkVærdi =  dkInput.value;
       let usdDK = dkInput.value/6.91;
       let gbpDK = dkInput.value/8.53;
       let euroDK = dkInput.value/7.54;


     usdInput.value = Number(usdDK).toFixed(2);
     dkInput.value = Number(dkVærdi).toFixed(2);
     gbpInput.value = Number(gbpDK).toFixed(2);
     euroInput.value = Number(euroDK).toFixed(2);
     })

     usdInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
     let usdVærdi = (usdInput.value);
     let dkTilUsd = (usdInput.value*6.91);
     let gbpTilUsd = usdInput.value * 0.81; 
     let euroTilUsd = usdInput.value * 0.91;

     usdInput.value = Number(usdVærdi).toFixed(2);
     dkInput.value = Number(dkTilUsd).toFixed(2);
     gbpInput.value = Number(gbpTilUsd).toFixed(2);
     euroInput.value = Number(euroTilUsd).toFixed(2);
     })

    gbpInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    let dollarsVærdi = (gbpInput.value*1.24);
    let dkkGbp = (gbpInput.value*8.54);
    let pund = gbpInput.value;
    let gbptilEuro = gbpInput.value * 1.13;

    usdInput.value = Number(dollarsVærdi).toFixed(2);
    dkInput.value = Number(dkkGbp).toFixed(2);
    gbpInput.value = Number(pund).toFixed(2);
    euroInput.value = Number(gbptilEuro).toFixed(2);
    })


    euroInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    let euroVærdi = (euroInput.value);
    let dkkEuro = (euroInput.value*7.55);
    let euroPund = euroInput.value*0.88;
    let euroDollars = euroInput.value * 1.10;

    usdInput.value = Number(euroDollars).toFixed(2);
    dkInput.value = Number(dkkEuro).toFixed(2);
    gbpInput.value = Number(euroPund).toFixed(2);
    euroInput.value = Number(euroVærdi).toFixed(2);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the String function in javascript then concatenating with the text.

```js
var test = "15.5";
console.log(String(test) + " GDP");
```

Comment: Thankyou for all the different responses! I got it fixed now with the String method.

Comment: No need for `String(test)` since `test` is already a string. Even if it were a number, it would be coerced to a string when concatenated with a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript Intarnalization API for this [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/introducing-the-javascript-internationalization-api/)

Example:

```
const number = 123456.789;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
```

// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ES Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const num = 123.853
const result = `${num.toFixed(2)} EUR`
// will echo "123.85 EUR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the border of your textbox transparent, place a span infront or behind it of it and a div with the same border as the textbox around it:

```
 <div style="border: 1px solid;">
     <span>€</span>
     <input type="text" style="border: none;" />
 </div>
```